# getting values from same id in while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a while loop in which i am getting different dates against each event.

```
 <?php while( have_rows('_event_date_time_slots') ): the_row(); ?>

 <div>
     <h3 class="date-<?php echo $post->ID?>" 
         name="tttdate<?php echo $post->ID?>"           
         value="<?php the_sub_field('_event_date'); ?>">
 <?php the_sub_field('_event_date'); ?></h3>
```

I have assigned class to h3 element to get dates in jquery with this code.

```
 var t_date = jQuery('.date-<?php echo $post->ID?>').html();
```

but it returns only first item. Then i assign name to h3 element and try to get dates by this code.

```
var tttdates = document.getElementsByName("tttdate<?php echo $post->ID?>");
var vals=[];
for (var i=0, n=tttdates.length; i<n; i++) {
     vals.push(tttdates[i].value);
}
alert(vals.join(","));
```

Now I am getting only , or empty alert box. where I am doing mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property, as `tttdates[i]` refer's [`<h3>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements) which doesn't have `value` property.

```
vals.push(tttdates[i].textContent);
```

As you are using jQuery, You can use `.map()`

```
var vals = $(".tttdate<?php echo $post->ID?>").map(function(){
    return this.textContent;
}).get();
```

Comment: thank you.
its nicely done.
i am passing dates in this format to get some output.
var availableDates = ['1-12-2017','5-12-2017'];
if i pass this, i don't get any output.
can you suggest something?
var availableDates = [vals.join(",")];

Comment: @shahidhamdam, I did't get above question?

Comment: i have to ask new question. plz wait

Comment: check this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485505/setting-dates-to-highlight-booked-dates-in-calendar-of-datepicker

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the same class using `each`.

Try this

```
$('.date-<?php echo $post->ID?>').each(function(i, obj) {
    vals.push($(obj).text());
});
alert(vals.join(","));
```