# setting dates to highlight booked dates in calendar of datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

i have this function that highlights the given dates and hide the others(not actually hide but undetectable).

```
var availableDates = ['1-12-2017','5-12-2017'];

  function availableFunction(date) {
      availday = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
      if (jQuery.inArray(availday, availableDates) > -1) {
          return [true,"eventday",""];
      } else {
          return [true,"ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled ",""];
      }
  }
```

Now i am gettings dates from database by jquery and pass to the above function.

```
var t_date = jQuery('.date-<?php echo $post->ID?>').html();
var availableDates = [t_date];
```

code still working fine but i want to get multiple dates and highlights them.
so i use this code.

```
var tttdates = document.getElementsByName("tttdate<?php echo $post->ID?>");
var vals=[];
for (var i=0, n=tttdates.length; i<n; i++) {
vals.push(tttdates[i].textContent);
}
alert(vals.join(","));
```

problem is that.

```
  var availableDates = [vals.join(",")];
```

i am not getting any dates highlighted.
why is that?

Comment: Just use `avaliableDates = vals;` no need for join